# If Zoidberg were cooked would he change color?

Tags: futurama

A lobster gets it's red color after being cooked. What would happen to Zoidberg's color if he were cooked? (I mean he is already cooked-lobster-red, so...?)

Answer (score 9):

As per the episode ["Anthology of Interest I"](http://theinfosphere.org/Anthology_of_Interest_I), Zoidberg would become an even darker shade of red. Compare his post-boiling appearance:

[image]

to his normal appearance:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When Scruffy was overcooking Zoidberg (on a spit over a fire) in "Lethal Inspection" he did not appear to change at all. The same is true in the first Anthology of Interest when Bender tries to make him into lobster bisque.

Answer (score 0):

Zoidberg doesn't appear to change color when he gets cooked. The only time he changes colors is when he "sheds" his skin, becoming a lighter shade of his current color. And a lot more slimy.